# How to group static/global variables together for improved cache locality in C++

Tags: c++, caching, micro-optimization, memory-layout

My understanding is that the C++ compiler is free to place program-wide variables wherever it wants, as long as they do not appear together in a struct.

```
//in .h
struct Singleton {
   static int hotvar1;
   static int hotvar2;
};

//in .cpp
//is placed at location x
int Singleton::hotvar1 = 0;
//is next to hotvar2, but placed at a random location
int Singleton::hotvar2 = 0;
```

versus

```
struct MyStruct {
   //is placed at memory address x
   int hotvar1;
   //is placed at memory address x+4, therefore probably in the same cacheline
   int hotvar2;
};
```

My program uses a lot of singletons, which contain many high-frequency read, low-frequency write variables. I have read in another thread, that many compilers use some sort of hashing algorithm for the placement of these program-wide variables in .bss or .data section, which is more than sub-optimal for cache locality.

Is there any method for grouping these variables together without losing data encapsulation by just putting all of these static vars into a single global struct?

Idea:

```
struct HotVars {
   int Singleton1::hotvar1 = 0;
   int Singleton2::hotvar2 = 0;
   int Singleton1::apiHandle = 0;
};
```

I know that this is some kind of micro optimisation, but my program is severely back-end bound so improving cache locality is definitely a good idea.

Comment: I haven't looked at how GCC or clang orders things within one object file, but I thought it was usually in definition order within the source file, or in reverse. Would be interesting to check if profile-guided optimization does anything. The linker won't reorder them, unless link-time optimization re-generates the BSS/data layout.

Comment: Yes, grouping with a struct is the only way to be sure, and could be a good idea if a lot of hot variables are in different cache lines that don't have anything else hot in them.  I guess you could try that as a test, and see if L1d miss rate code down measurably; as a proxy for seeing if the working-set size shrank.